Test execution MS.Test V3.5.3 DataTestMethod only one test visible
I've upgraded my legacy unitest platform to the latest version of MS.TestFramework V3.4.3 to be able to write Data driven test by usage of [DataTestMethod] & [DataRow] attributes.
My testing framework is built in abstract way to run both API and Webservices tests. The way how it should execute tests its defined by test category attribute and filtering done on pipeline level.
Test Class implementation looks as following :
    [TestClass]
    public class ApiHistoryTests : AllApiTestBase
    {
    public ApiHistoryTests()
    {
    }

    [DataTestMethod]
    [TestCategory("WebAPI")]
    [TestCategory("SOAP")]
    [Priority(1)]
    [DataRow("History - Document Name", "test2", "test1")]
    [DataRow("History - Document Name", "test1", null)]
     public void X_Y_Z_TEST(string titleSetting, string field1, string field2)

In Visual Studio my tests(2) are visible and executable without any problem but the problem starts when it comes to the Pipeline and execution of them on Azure. Tests are executed on different environments (filtered by criteria). When SOAP tests are executed than two tests are discovered and executed but if it's WebAPI than it's only 1 (first) executed.
Im using .net472 with Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK 17.10
When checkin logs between these two stages I can see difference in execution (which to be hones I don't know where it comes from)
WebAPI:
024-06-19T07:37:56.1873197Z Discovering tests from sources
2024-06-19T07:37:56.1969717Z Using new test platform for test execution
2024-06-19T07:37:56.2088724Z Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleWrapper instance will be created
2024-06-19T07:38:01.2795503Z **************** Starting test execution *********************
2024-06-19T07:38:01.2844479Z Using new test platform for test execution
2024-06-19T07:38:01.2844880Z Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleWrapper instance will be created

SOAP:
 **************** Starting test execution *********************
2024-06-18T09:40:48.2708107Z [command]C:\TestAgent\_work\_tool\VsTest\17.1.0\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@C:\TestAgent\_work\_temp\xdn1tlpbrvz.tmp"
2024-06-18T09:40:48.3381835Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.1.0
2024-06-18T09:40:48.3382290Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2024-06-18T09:40:48.3416326Z vstest.console.exe "C:\Test\API\Therefore.Test.ApiCore.dll"

both of tests are executed via Visual studio task
I've tried to change to output of project build folder to the \API\ to include only the TestAdapter of MSTest.TestAdapter but it did not helped.
Stages configuration is the same. There is no specific configuration on pipeline. I
Im expecting that both stages will discover the same tests and will execute them the same way.
To be honest I don't know what else to do.
This is release pipeline so it's hard to copy all tasks, Two most common staff
WebAPI
variables:
  TestPlatformVersion: '17.1.0'

steps:
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install Visual Studio Test Platform'
  inputs:
    versionSelector: specificVersion
    testPlatformVersion: '$(TestPlatformVersion)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Execute Tests on Agent - Part 1'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: Test.ApiCore.dll
    searchFolder: 'C:\Test\API'
    testFiltercriteria: '$(TestFilterCriteria)
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    runSettingsFile: '$(TestRunArchitecture).runsettings'
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    distributionBatchType: basedOnExecutionTime
    dontDistribute: false
    testRunTitle: 'Web API Tests ($(TestRunArchitecture)) Part 1'
    platform: '$(ConfigurationName)'
    configuration: 'WebAPI ($(TestRunArchitecture)) @ $(OSInfo)'
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunType: basedOnTestFailureCount
    rerunFailedTestCasesMaxLimit: 10
    rerunMaxAttempts: 1
  continueOnError: true
  timeoutInMinutes: 40

SOAP
variables:
  TestPlatformVersion: '17.1.0'

steps:
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'VsTest Platform Installer'
  inputs:
    versionSelector: specificVersion
    testPlatformVersion: '$(TestPlatformVersion)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Execute Tests on Agent '
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: Test.ApiCore.dll
    searchFolder: 'C:\Test\API'
    testFiltercriteria: '$(TestFilterCriteria)'
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    runSettingsFile: $(TestRunArchitecture).runsettings'
    dontDistribute: true
    testRunTitle: 'API Tests ($(TestRunArchitecture)) Part 1 - $(Agent.Name)'
    platform: '$(ConfigurationName)'
    configuration: 'API ($(TestRunArchitecture)) @ $(OSInfo)'
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunType: basedOnTestFailureCount
    rerunFailedTestCasesMaxLimit: 10
    rerunMaxAttempts: 1
  continueOnError: true


Provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline to run the test task?

@BrightRan-MSFT it's release pipeline, I've added yaml for vastest platform installer and also visual studio test

From YAML you provided, I noticed that the two pipelines are testing with different assembly files. WebAPI is Test.Api.dll and SOAP is Test.ApiCore.dll. Have you checked the code of the assembly file Test.Api.dll to ensure the tests specified by testFiltercriteria have been defined? Can you provide more details code of the test assembly files? @matahari32

I've deleted too much from the they refer to the same Test.ApiCore.dll I had to correct it.

Sure, please go ahead and check the code to ensure the test methods you require are defined in the assembly file. @matahari32

It's fixed. The problem was because of these two guys. distributionBatchType: basedOnExecutionTime
dontDistribute: false

In addition, you also can try to manually call the VSTest.Console.exe command with the same parameters on you local machine to see if it can work. @matahari32

The problem of this behavior was because on the WebAPI stage, it was set:
distributionBatchType: basedOnExecutionTime
dontDistribute: false

I changed it to be based on the number of agents and then it started to execute tests the same way as it does with SOAP.

Glad that you can figure out the solution. Maybe, you can access this answer by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues. @matahari32
